# Using QVTKWidget

Tags: python, qt4, vtk

I developed a QT4 GUI where `QVTKWidget` is used. I'm trying to use this widget in Python code but I don't know how.

The command:

```
from vtk import QVTKWidged
```

didn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prueba.py", line 6, in <module>
from Ui_MainWindowVtk import Ui_MainWindow
File "/home/usuario/PRINCIPAL/MECANICA COMPUTACIONAL/Varios/VTK/Ui_MainWindowVtk.py",
line 59, in <module>
    from vtk import QVTKWidget
ImportError: cannot import name QVTKWidget
```

How Can I use `QVTKWidget` in Python?

Comment: It seems that there is no QVTKWidget in vtk modules for python. Somes guys on the VTK forum and others sites used a `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor`, works with PyQt4 and vtk modules. I've never tested

Answer (score 0):

I have always used `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` when using VTK from Python.  In fact, you can and should take the `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.py` source file that is found in the resulting Python wrappings folder, typically something like:

`...Wrapping/Python/vtk/qt/QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.py`

of your VTK build and modify it to fit your needs.

I just checked and it looks like this file has been updated substantially from the last time I modified it, so try using it out of the box first.

Comment: Just noticed that you are using PyQt4.  There is a qt4 folder in there as well with this file.  It basically just imports the file from the qt folder anyway.